# Communication between injected components

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, communication

My application contains a UI in the MVC with several controllers that get injected via spring. Some Controllers are creating events like login into a data connection. All other controller are depending on these events and therefore they need to be informed.

What is a proper way to use a lightweight communication between these injected components? I looked into Spring Integration but it seemed to be a bit overkill. MessageSystems like ActiveMQ are also not fitting for the task because the application should a single standalone client.

Comment: Show some code, please

Comment: I assume you want to do asynchronous calls between the components, if this is the case, Spring integration is OK (it's basically an in-memory queue, I'm not sure why you find it overkill).. otherwise use simple `LinkedBlockingQueue` from the concurrent package to communicate between the components..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `@Async` [25.5.2 The @Async Annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html)?